# BQ copy table command change column mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I ran below command to create a new table from an existing table. Problem is BQ creates this new table but change mode of REQUIRED columns to NULLABLE

```
create table `project_id.dataset.new_table_name` as 
select * replace(
    array(select as struct person.* except(add) from t.person) as person
  )
from `project_id.dataset.table_name` t;
```

Expecting column mode unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The NOT NULL attribute of a table's column_schema does not propagate through queries over the table. If table T contains a column declared as x INT64 NOT NULL, for example, CREATE TABLE dataset.newtable AS SELECT x FROM T creates a table named dataset.newtable in which x is NULLABLE.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#column_name_and_column_schema

So, you'd better consider explicit schema definition.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project_id.dataset.table_name` (
  Id STRING,
  Person ARRAY<STRUCT<
    Name STRING NOT NULL,
    Add STRUCT<line STRING>
  >>
) AS
SELECT 'id', [('John', STRUCT('aaa'))];

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project_id.dataset.new_table_name` (
  Id STRING,
  Person ARRAY<STRUCT<
    Name STRING NOT NULL
  >>
) AS
SELECT * REPLACE (ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT Person.* EXCEPT(add) FROM t.Person) AS Person)
  FROM `project_id.dataset.table_name` t;
```